# How to traverse through a tree to find the lowest value

Tags: algorithm, tree, traversal

Given a graph, starting from a specified node (orange in example), how would one go about getting the lowest value leaf node (green in example)?

It is not binary, therefore one node could have hundreds of children. Children are not guaranteed to have a lower value than their parent.

Is there a better way than simply iterating through every single branch? If not, then we could collect all leaves into a set to find the lowest-valued leaf.

Unfortunately, this would be very costly.

[image]

Comment: If you have no structure in your tree (some kind of order) than you need to iterate it all.

Comment: You don't really need to collect all leaf nodes into a set, keeping a global min value is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

A tree traversal is the way to do such a thing if there is no particular property on your tree.
This pseudocode describes a possible way to do so:

```
find_min(node):
    result = node.value
    for each child of node:
        child_min = find_min(child)
        if child_min < result:
            result = child_min
    return result
```

But ultimately, you will have to go though all the branches of you tree. That is because to find the min, you have to go though all the nodes of your tree, and thus traverse it. There is no faster method in the general case, since this runs in `O(n)`, with `n` the number of nodes in your tree.
It is also the simplest method, other approaches would be more complex, and thus more error prone.